# DEBUG directive in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to use some kind of DEBUG directive in JS code causing debug code not to be included in production? Examples:

```
// #if debug
console.log('Initializing');
// #endif

var url =
// #if debug
    '/foo/debug';
// #else
    '/foo';
// #endif
```

Comment: Javascript isn't a compiled language, so this type of behavior is not possible. You can add a compile step of course, and that step can remove things like console.log form your code.

Comment: I'm not agree. While developing we have a lot of tools like preprocessors, autocomplete, intellisence with comments etc. There could be a tool also for this.

Comment: You can do that if you don't mind preprocessing your script. I'm doing this with my FF plugin, using ant and cpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But you can simply replace `console.log` with a dummy function for production:

```
window.console = window.console || {};
window.console.log = function() { /* do nothing */ };
```

Then you just need to configure your build tools (assuming you have some) to include that code only in production builds.

Comment: i'd add an "if" to prevent overriding existing console depending on when this line is executed : if !(("console" in window)) { window.console = { log: function() {} }; }

Comment: @ThiefMaster please look at the one more example. Can you please provide any idea for it also?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define global variables:

```
var DEBUG = true;

// Somewhere else:
if (DEBUG)
    console.log('Initializing');
```

But it doesn't have any language features like `#define`.